# Fixing spatial query in GeoDjango

Tags: geodjango

I am new to Geodjango. and I am following the steps given in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#

and the steps I followed before https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#spatial-queries were working fine but after that I got error in the

```
qs = WorldBorder.objects.filter(mpoly__contains=pnt_wkt)
```

in this Statement.

Error it is showing is

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'mpoly' into field. Choices are: area, fips, geom, id, 
iso2, iso3, lat, lon, name, pop2005, region, subregion, un
```

and if I am executing this line

```
sm = WorldBorder.objects.get(name='San Marino')
```

Then Error is

```
DatabaseError: column world_worldborder.geom does not exist
LINE 1: ...ld_worldborder"."lon", "world_worldborder"."lat", "world_wor...
```

Answer (score 5):

You changed your schema and the underlying tables did not get updated. When I develop on Django, I usually change my schema quite often. Unless you want to manually sync your fields through raw SQL (or even worse - drop the tables and re-create them), I would recommend you use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part1.html) which is the de facto standard to keep your Django models and your DB in sync.

Answer (score 1):

From my tiny experience with GeoDjango, you must sync your daatabase quite often until you fully define your model.

Why don't you try dropping all tables created by django and then recreating them via **syncdb**?

I'm not sure if that might help, but these are basic column errors, so that might help out. On the other side, can you start up the django dev server using **runserver**? The runserver command validates all models against database (remember that you application must be listed in settings.py).